# For loop using str.replace()

Tags: python

New to python, trying to figure out how to replace words using a dict.

It is setup like:

```
list = {"word1":"word2",
     "word3":"word4",
     "word5":"word6"
      }
```

I have :

```
for w in list:
    new_list = old_list.replace(w)
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a `list`, but a `dict` and furthermore you better don't name your list a `list`...

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type; and calling a `dict` "list" is doubly-confusing.

Comment: Furthermore are the words really words? (Separated by word boundaries)?

Comment: What is `old_list`? Is it a string? It'd help us to understand and answer your question if you gave us a little bit of typical data.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. What's the desired result/output?

Comment: Right, the dict isn't named list and uses real words. old_list is a html file.

Comment: Please show us the value of `old_list` before executing this code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can't perform string replacements directly on a file object. You need to read the data from the file into a string first, then you can easily do the replacement with code that's quite similar to what you have posted. As I said earlier, it would help if you posted a small snippet of proper sample data and expected output (and a `dict` with proper words instead of the "word1" stuff).

Comment: sorry, it was not didactically correct to answer your question after all the edits that have been requested. I guess I interpreted your question correctly nevertheless. Please show more effort for a nice question next time :)

Comment: FWIW, we aren't doing this to be pedantic. We're trying to help you put your question into a clear form so that people who want to answer it don't have to guess what you _really_ mean. And that will also make your question more useful to future readers.

Comment: Thankyou all, obviously didn't make it easy to read and understand. Thank you all for your help nonetheless. I need to think more about wording my question so it can be understood, your frustration is understandable! Next time it'll be better.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? And as others have pointed out, "list" is already used in Python, so don't call your dict "list".

Comment: It's still not too late to fix _this_ question. Sure, you now have an answer, but remember that SO is supposed to be a repository of good questions and answers, so it would be nice to make this question useful for future readers as well. And if you do that, your downvote will probably get reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, `list` is a built-in name, and you have overwritten it - this might cause weird behaviour.

Your syntax for creating the dictionary is correct, but let's call it `my_dict`.
Now what are you trying to do? Your title suggets, that you want to replace substrings and not elements in lists?

Anyway, the `for`-loop loops over the keys of the dictionary. So inside it you should do `my_string.replace(my_dict, my_dict[w])`

Alternatively, you can loop over the key-value-pairs: `for k, v in my_dict.items()`. Inside this loop you can use `my_string.replace(k, v)`

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to explain! Thank you, this helps, obviously being my first question here I did things the wrong way. Next time it'll be better!

Comment: you are welcome, it's indeed excusable for the first question :)